# Set key or value dynamically in tidyr::gather

Tags: r, tidyr

I know there is `gather_()` but its not working with `matches` and so ...

```
    dynamicKey  = "coolKey"

    mtcars[,8:11] %>% gather(dynamicKey,values,matches("vs|am"))

   gear carb dynamicKey values
1     4    4         vs      0
2     4    4         vs      0
3     4    1         vs      1
4     3    1         vs      1
5     3    2         vs      0
6     3    1         vs      1
...
```

## Desired result

```
   gear carb    coolKey values
1     4    4         vs      0
2     4    4         vs      0
3     4    1         vs      1
4     3    1         vs      1
5     3    2         vs      0
6     3    1         vs      1
...
```

#### My effords

google, SO, `get(dynamicKey)` ... nothing works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unquote the dynamic key argument, either with the UQ function or with the equivalent double-bang notation:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dynamicKey  = "coolKey"

mtcars[,8:11] %>% gather(key = !!dynamicKey,value = values,matches("vs|am"))
```

Output:

```
   gear carb coolKey values
1     4    4      vs      0
2     4    4      vs      0
3     4    1      vs      1
4     3    1      vs      1
5     3    2      vs      0
6     3    1      vs      1 ...
```

Same thing but with UQ instead of the double bang:

```
> mtcars[,8:11] %>% gather(key = UQ(dynamicKey),value = values,matches("vs|am"))
   gear carb coolKey values
1     4    4      vs      0
2     4    4      vs      0
3     4    1      vs      1
4     3    1      vs      1
5     3    2      vs      0
6     3    1      vs      1...
```

Comment: Glad to have helped. The non-standard evaluation methods used in the tidyverse are at times obstacles which make what should be simple a bit more difficult to implement.

Comment: "Error: Invalid column specification". Why doesnt it work for me? I have `dplyr` loaded and copied your expression.

Comment: Updated my `tidyr` package. That solved the problem!